# Get the correct event.currentTarget

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a listing of an array, when i click an item of this list i activate a sorting by the current note, and when i click again i deactivate the current note as you can see in the function below :

```
createdNotesSort = (e) => {
    const { createdNotes } = this.state;
    let typeNote = +e.currentTarget.value;
    const index = createdNotes.indexOf(typeNote);
    index === -1
        ? this.setState({
            createdNotes: [...createdNotes, typeNote].sort((a, b) => b - a)
        }, () => {
          this.reloadData()
        })
        : this.setState({
          createdNotes: createdNotes.filter(val => val !== typeNote)
        }, () => {
          this.reloadData()
        });
}
```

I also map through the array **createdNotes** so i can add beside each item a close button so i can deactivate from a second menu. Everytime i click a note in the second menu, it seems that there is no connection with the currentTarget.value of the first menu (initial listing) the second menu items invoke the function below (remove the **currentTarget.value** from the array) it does remove an item, but not always the current item. What am i missing?

```
handleResetCreated = (e) => {
    const { createdNotes } = this.state;
    let typeCreated = +e.currentTarget.value;
    const newCreatedNotes = createdNotes.filter((_, i) => i !== typeCreated);
    this.setState({
        createdNotes: newCreatedNotes,
    }, () => {
      this.reloadData()
    })
};
```

Comment: A working example may end up being necessary here, but one thing that seems off to me is that you are accessing the `value` property of an element.  `currentTarget` is the element that is the target of your event, but `value` is a property of only certain HTML elements, notably (and perhaps only?) the `<input>` element.  Since you haven't mentioned anything to do with `<input>` here, I find the use of `value` kind of weird.  But again, it's hard to tell without a full example.  If this comment is way off base and not helpful at all, then providing a CodeSandbox link or similar would be great!

Comment: don't u think it's because of createdNotes: createdNotes.filter(val => val !== typeNote) in the first function and const newCreatedNotes = createdNotes.filter((_, i) => i !== typeCreated); in the second one?

Comment: It's very difficult to say, since I can't really see the relationship between your two snippets of code, or what your DOM looks like.

Comment: i have fixed it by removing the typeCreated variable and changing the newCreatedNotes variable to const newCreatedNotes = createdNotes.filter(val => val !== value); in the handleResetCreated = (e, value) => {}